# How to show real time data on a windows and a web application?

Tags: .net, trading

We are starting a new windows application which simulates the trading platform. We want to implement this application using .NET technologies, especially with WPF.

Though it's a simulation project, the prices comes real time.

The pricing server generates price for every instrument(stock) in real time(propably in milli seconds). And we have around 1,000 stocks like that and there will be around 100 traders sitting at their terminal and waiting to see real time data.

Could you please tell me what mechanism I would employ to get the pricing details across?

Also, please let me know what is the method in case if it is a web application?

Thanks a lot.

Mahesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options. Look for Server push or [WebORB](http://www.themidnightcoders.com/products/weborb-for-net/overview.html) or [WebSync](http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync/). Basically,you are looking for componentry that will allow a push mechanism from server to client. HTML, as is, does not support push from the server but some clever mechanisms such as Comet (long polling) exist.